# Format a calculated field as Date SQL Script for Qlik Sense

Tags: sql, oracle, qliksense

Database is in oracle, my machine has odbc 32 bits configured with the name PPM and I've created a script but need assistance formatting a calculated field:

```
LIB CONNECT TO [PPM];

[SCRIPT]:

SQL Select NP.BUSINESS, NP.PLATFORM, NP.CATEGORY,

CASE WHEN IMPLE IS not NULL THEN IMPLE
                WHEN CONTRACT IS not NULL THEN CONTRACT
                    WHEN ANALYSIS IS not NULL THEN ANALYSIS
                        ELSE IDEA END AS REALDATE,
```

Imple, Contact, Analysis, Idea are all fields with same format of dates and this code is needed so we can have always the last date input as "Realdate"

This gives back a correct Date in the new field (doesn't exist in the server) but shows many duplicates, using `SET TimestampFormat='MM-YYYY';` before, it gives back the dates with the correct format but shows "03-2015" 3 times and many others dates like that. 
 Trying also: `date(floor("REALDATE",'MM.YYYY') as "REALDATE2"` but since this is a calculated field I don't know how to make reference that field.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way around after long hours of trying:

```
DATE#(DATE(Date#([REALDATE], 'MM-YYYY'), 'MMM/YYYY'), 'MMM/YYYY')
```

Could not format the field inside the script but this does the trick

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

In QlikView, the function Date#(expression [ , format-code ]) could help you. You can evaluate any expression with a specific date format.

Hope this could help, but your question is not very clear, if you could add more information it would be very useful.

Comment: Would this be in the script or after that, trying on both, Date# or Date but it keeps showing an error and the data wont load.

Comment: Try using a Preceding Load, something like LOAD 
        *,
        Date#(Floor(REALDATE)) as REALDATE2; before the SQL command.

Comment: no error, just numbers like: (41700, 41760, etc...)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Qlik is picking up the numeric value and needs to be converted to a date. `date#` is used to render date strings into a date value.

```
LIB CONNECT TO [PPM];

[SCRIPT]:
Load BUSINESS
,PLATFORM
,CATEGORY
,date(REALDATE) as REALDATE;
SQL Select NP.BUSINESS, NP.PLATFORM, NP.CATEGORY,

CASE WHEN IMPLE IS not NULL THEN IMPLE
                WHEN CONTRACT IS not NULL THEN CONTRACT
                    WHEN ANALYSIS IS not NULL THEN ANALYSIS
                        ELSE IDEA END AS REALDATE,
```

Comment: [SCRIPT]:
Load date(REALDATE,'MM,YYYY') as REALDATE;
This shows duplicates is there any way to make qlik sense to show 16/06/2016 and 17/06/2016 inside the filter of 06/2016 when using the MM,YYYY format

Comment: @MVZ Load date(monthstart(REALDATE),'MM,YYYY') as REALDATE